# npm start doesnt work and even node <filename>.js cannot find mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble with my express project. Every time i try to run  `npm run` i get this error:

```
  Linux 4.9.17-c9
 npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/node" 
 "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/npm" "start"
 npm ERR! node v6.11.2
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
 npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json
 npm ERR! code ENOENT
 npm ERR! errno -2
 npm ERR! syscall open

 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json'
 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json'
 npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
 npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
 npm ERR! enoent 

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/npm-debug.log
```

I can run `npm install` just fine, and npm run was running before i started adding files. Im trying to connect a shop.js file to config/mongodb.js file in the index file: this is what i have so far.

model/product.js

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  var schema = new Schema({

  imagePath: {type: String, required:true},
 title: {type: String, required:true},
 description: {type: String, required:true},
 price: {type: Number, required:true}

  });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);}
```

in my config/mongoose.js

```
 var config = require('../config'),
 mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect(config.db_uri, {
 useMongoClient: true
 });
```

in a seed/product-seeder.js

```
 var Product = require("../model/product");
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')
 var config = require('../config');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



 var products = [
 new Product({
imagePath:'theNymphets15.png',
title: 'Nymphs1',
description: 'Awesome jacket',
price: 45
 }), 
 new Product({
imagePath:'theNymphets22.png',
title: 'Nymphs2',
description: 'Awesome pants',
price: 60
 }),
 new Product({
imagePath:'theNymphets25.png',
title: 'Nymphs3',
description: 'Awesome shirt',
price: 55
 }),


 ];

 var done =0;

 for (var i=0; i<products.length; i++) {
 products[i].save(function(err, result){
    done++;
    if (done === products.length){
        exit(); 
    }
});
}
 function exit(){
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

in my controllers/shop.js file

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next){ 
 router.get('/', users.list);
 module.exports = router;
```

in my routers/shop.js

```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  var products = require('../controllers/shop');
  /* GET products listing. */
  router.get('/', products.list);
  module.exports = router;
```

and finally in my views/index.js file

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var products = require('../model/products');
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     var products = products.find();
    res.render('shop', {"title": "mytitle", products:products});

   });


 module.exports = router;
```

my package.json file looks like this:

```
 {
 "name": "proj",
 "version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
 "scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www",
"devstart": "DEBUG=express:* nodemon ./bin/www"
 },
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.18.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"ejs": "^2.5.7",
"express": "~4.15.5",
"jade": "~1.11.0",
"mongodb": "^2.2.33",
"morgan": "~1.9.0",
"serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
"mongoose": "^4.13.6"

 },
"devDependencies": {
"nodemon": "^1.12.1"
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a package.json file?

Comment: yes this is my package.json file  {
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "DEBUG=express:* nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.6"
    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  }
}

Comment: first of all you should have edit your question instead of posting your package.json in comment... it seems that you don't call any js file in your start command but just a folder ....

Comment: sorry im new to this, but what does that mean i should do? i just added the package.json in the edit